# Remove Checkbox Border with iTextSharp

Tags: itext, acrobat

I'm working with a pdf which has a bunch of acrofield checkboxes. My objective is to make the checkbox border invisible.

I'm able to do so using Adobe Acrobat by going to the checkbox's `Properties -> Appearance -> Border Color = No Color`.

Now I'd like to accomplish the same thing programatically with `iTextSharp`. I do this as follows:

```
            fields.SetFieldProperty(f, "bordercolor", null, null);
```

After doing this, when I go back and open the file using Acrobat, the checkbox's `Properties -> Appearance -> Border Color` is, indeed, set to  `No Color`, yet strangely the border is still visible. Adobe Reader, however,  does seem to render it properly.

What is going on here, and how can I fix this?

Comment: There's probably still a border dictionary for the widget annotation. I bet this border dictionary defines a border width and that a default border color is used when the color is No Color. I should see the PDF to make sure. (Please don't expect any further answer as long as you don't share the PDF.)

Comment: Is the PDF created using OpenOffice? We've noticed that OO puts (parts of) the appearance in the content stream.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey I didn't create the pdf.

Comment: Check the document properties for the Producer line.